# How to split utf-8 string with a number ahead it in python?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, split, mojibake

I got a raw utf-8 string:

```
u'1\u670d-\u82f1\u96c4\u96c6\u7ed3'
```

And I convert it to string

```
s = str(u'1\u670d-\u82f1\u96c4\u96c6\u7ed3'.encode('utf8'))
print s
'1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93'
```

I want to separate that number 1 with the rest of the strings.

Then I tried:

```
s.split('\\')
['1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93']

s.split('\\x')
['1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93']
```

Not what I thought it will be.

Finally a sparkle comes to my mind, I did:

```
s.split('\xe6')
['1', '\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93']
```

But the problem is, I can't ensure the utf-8 code in other such combinations would start with '\xe6', so I need a method to distinguish a number with arbitrary utf-8 code and then split them apart.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: "I need a method to distinguish a number with arbitrary utf-8 code and then split them apart." - this is not clear to me, what exactly are you trying to do and why (what are you trying to achieve) ?

Comment: @alfasin, it's simple, I need to handle lots of such items in the job, they were kind of mark for users.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to handle" ? why are you splitting it in an arbitrary place ? what will you do with the output ? if you'll bother explaining *what* are you trying to do (achieve) instead of *how* you're trying to do it - someone might come up with a better approach.

Comment: It will not in arbitrary place, the unicode could be arbitrary. I need to get that number to do numeric rank. Basically, icktoofay's answer already meets this general purpose.

Comment: Please read my answer bellow . If you are getting these strings they are being incorrectly encoded in some process there - I show the correct way of dealing with them bellow, rather than trying to extract the hex-codes and reconstruct a new string from that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s always a single digit, just index the first item:

```
digit = s[0]
```

Otherwise, you could use a regular expression to scan it:

```
number = re.match(r'^\d+', s).group(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Beware there -- what you presented us as a "raw utf-8 string" could not be more different than that.

Most important first, though it should be in the end: the final decoding of your string reveals a valid phrase in Chinese - which spills out an apparently valid translation in Google-transate: "1 Hero build":
[image]

Second thing: Stop any thing you are doing now, and read [the classic post on Unicode from "Joel on Software"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). For real  - it will make you good - don't let the title make you feel like you are being mocked upon - read that.

Third - now, let's get to what is wrong in your data - what you have there is a Python Unicode object, not a "raw utf-8 string". 
When you encode that particular string to ut-8, correctly, you get a string (bytes) object which reads literally  `'1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93'`  - if you put that in an `s` variable, and get the character at index 1,as you found out, you have a slash (`\`) character - that is, the slashes you showed us here are not being used as part of an escape sequence to encode the bytes "0xe6, 0x9c" , etc...as characters - they are literally there. Its `repr` is `'1\\xe6\\x9c\\x8d-\\xe8\\x8b\\xb1\\xe9\\x9b\\x84\\xe9\\x9b\\x86\\xe7\\xbb\\x93'`

However, they should be just that - part of an escape sequence - so what you have to do is to  decode your (byte) string `s` back to unicode, but using the special "unicode_escape" codec -- that will give you an unicode object in which the literal slashes are in fact escaping characters  for the hex-byte codes they preceed:

```
>>> print s, repr(s)
1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93 '1\\xe6\\x9c\\x8d-\\xe8\\x8b\\xb1\\xe9\\x9b\\x84\\xe9\\x9b\\x86\\xe7\\xbb\\x93'
>>> s1 = s.decode("unicode_escape")
>>> print repr(s1)
u'1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93'
```

That unicode object is meaningless as unicode, but its raw bytes content is the actual final string in utf-8:

```
>>> print s1
1æ-è±ééç»
```

The "latin-1" transform, due mostly to a coincidence, not because "it is such" transposes the bytes in the unicode object as they are to an ordinary (bytes) string. This is not "a thing of unicode" - it is due to a coincidence that the values 0-255 of the internal representation of a Python unicode object match the latin-1 encoding - so encoding in "latin-1" provides a "transparent" encoding. Nothing in the standards would mandate that. This string, when viewed as UTF-8 *(N.B., I am using the Python interactive interpreter in an utf-8 console - what you see could be different in a Python prompt using latin-1 or other encoding)* reveals what most certainly is the intended string in this case:

```
>>> s2 = s1.encode("latin-1")

>>> print repr(s2)
'1\xe6\x9c\x8d-\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe9\x9b\x86\xe7\xbb\x93'

>>> print s2
1服-英雄集结
```

Comment: Educating answer, I've read it through, except the recommended article. Read it later when have more time. Thank you, @jsbueno

Comment: You really should read that. Do it before writing even another line of code. It will spare you a lot of headaches and time.